# Kotlin Gson toJson returns double quoted string

Tags: kotlin, gson

I am trying to encode JSON object from Kotlin object:

```
class RequestData(val phone: String)

...

val requestJson = Gson().toJson(RequestData("79008007060"))
```

After encoding I am getting quoted string

```
"{\"phoneNumber\":\"\"}"
```

instead

```
{"phoneNumber":""}
```

Could you tell me why does it happen and how to fix it?

Comment: Unable to reproduce. Did you perhaps do `toJson` on the `requestJson` a second time? Or are you inspecting the contents of `requestJson` in some sort of a debugger, rather than printing it out?

Comment: How do you observe the vaslue?

Comment: My bad. I tried send POST JSON request and put json-string to @Body instead object as needed... :( Sorry for incorrect question! Ready for dislikes...

Comment: @pirogtm this is not an invalid question. You could answer yourself with how you observed the value and why it was giving you this result. It might help others in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution. I made mistake in other place. I tried to send POST JSON request to server with Retrofit and encoded object to JSON-string before put it to @Body:

```
interface AuthService {
    @POST("requestPinCode")
    fun requestPinCode(@Body body: String): Observable<ApiResult>
}

...

data class RequestData(val phone: String)

...

val requestJson = Gson().toJson(RequestData("79008007060"))
authService.requestPinCode(requestJson)
```

But right way is to put not encoded object to @Body

```
interface AuthService {

    @POST("requestPinCode")
    fun requestPinCode(@Body body: RequestData): Observable<ApiResult>

}

...

data class RequestData(val phone: String)

...

authService.requestPinCode(RequestData("79008007060"))
```